# Unable to display nested JSON on Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Consider this JSON

```
{
    "stream": {
        "posts": [{
            "post_id": "1",
            "post_type": "text",
            "post_thumb": "bla1",
            "comments": [{
                "comment_id": "7",
                "comment_text": "asd",
            },
            {
                "comment_id": "8",
                "comment_text": "sdf",
            }],
        }],
    }
}
```

and my Model

```
Ext.define('MyAppApp.model.Post', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'post_id',
            'post_type',
            'post_thumb',
            'comments',
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url:  'http://MyApp.com/home/index_app',
            reader: {
                type:         'json',
                rootProperty: 'stream'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The above correctly shows a list of posts in my view.
I added a controller to push a panel to show the full content of each post, which is working.

Controller

```
Ext.define('MyAppApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            stream: 'homepanel'
        },
        control: {
            'homepanel list': {
                itemtap: 'showPost'
            }
        }
    },

    showPost: function(list, index, element, record) {

/////// begin code block that solved my problem

    var data     = record.get('comments');
    var comments = '';

    Ext.Array.each(data, function(item) {
        comments += [item.comment_text] + '<br />';
    });

/////// end 

        this.getStream().push({
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: [
                '<p>' + record.get('post_thumb') + '</p>',
                '<p>' + record.get('comments') + '</p>',
                comments     // added to output HTML
            ].join(''),
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
        });
    }
});
```

**My trouble is with retrieving the data from `comments`, which are nested in the JSON.**

With the above controller, I get

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

in my view and in the console I can open those objects and see the entirety of my comments.

But how do I display them in the view? (eg, how do I display `"comment_text"`?)

Comment: I edited my post a last time, because if possible don't use Ext.Array.each or even any functioncall within a loop. But this is more a best practice example. But I felt the need to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they are no longer JSON as soon as they are in your model, they got deserialized to object. To display them you should use a **[XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)**. If you already use a template within your view you can directly access the properties of the objects to to render them. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Why exactly do you render the content by yourself into html property? Is that cause of performance reasons? I am not that used to ST, therefore I ask. Anyway, build up a little helper function that will loop through the comment array and return is as more or less formatted string (this will be up to you, also the check that the array is at least a empty one and never null)

```
var data = record.get('comments')
function(data) {
    var result = '',
        len = data.length,
        i=0;

    for(;i<len;i++) {
        result += data[i]['comment_text'] +'<br />'
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is a implementation into the origin function. I post this cause the use of Ext.Array.each is not recommend, because it executes a function for each element and functioncalls within loops should be spared.

```
showPost: function(list, index, element, record) {
        var data     = record.get('comments');

        function fetchComments(data) {
            var result = '',
                len = data.length,
                i = 0;

            for(;i<len;i++) {
                result += data[i]['comment_text'] + '<br />';
            }

            return result;
        }

        this.getStream().push({
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: [
                '<p>' + record.get('post_thumb') + '</p>',
                '<p>' + fetchComments(data) + '</p>'
            ].join(''),
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks @sra - but where exactly should I put that loop in my original code - and how do I output it in the HTML? While I can loop and send the comments to the console, I've been unable to put this code inside the `html:[...]`

Comment: @torr Define the function within the controller using 'yourName: function()' same as you did it with showPist() and set the 'var data=...' as first within your showPost function. Now you call it instead of 'record.get('comments')'

Comment: @torr I am mobile atm, I can show you slightly other ways in about 2hours. If you still need. But I think the example should be fine.

Comment: thx for checking while on mobile... ;) ... fyi I'm getting a syntax error due to an unexpected token `(` when inserting the code.. we can catch up later on this

Comment: nevermind - I got it working and added the code in OP - thx for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Here is the other way I have iterated.

Json data:

```
{
    "account" : [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "accNo" : "5869785254",
            "curAmt" : "25000",
            "balAmt" : "15000",
            "transdate" : [
                {
                    "date" : "10",
                    "month" : "03",
                    "description" : "Check 232",
                    "crddbt" : "-1200"
                },
                {
                    "date" : "14",
                    "month" : "03",
                    "description" : "ATM Withdrawl",
                    "crddbt" : "-500"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Sencha Code to iterate on transdate object.

```
var transDateObj = record.get('transdate');

Ext.Object.each(transDateObj, function(key, value, myself){

            Ext.Object.each(value, function(key, value, myself){
                console.log(key + ":" + value);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thnx to SRA. 

First I was using Sencha Ext.Object.each class to iterate on same object but it didn, Sra code give me a click! so try to use same Ext.Object.each for its each values so got the same result.